# Can I move common code from a method into a base controller with MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following method in five controllers:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string page, string title) {
        var vm = new BaseViewModel(); 
        vm.Role = GetRoleNumber(User);
        vm.MenuItems = contentService.GetMenuItems("00", vm.Role);
        vm.Menu = pageService.GetMenu(vm.MenuItems, Request.FilePath);

        // difference code here for each controller
    }
```

All my controllers inherit from a controller called BaseController.

Is there a way I could move this code into my base controller and call it? If so then what would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

This is an exact candidate for the Repository Pattern. 
You could create all of these in your Repository class and call that method in each ActionResult method

```
public void Repository : IRepository
{
   public GetMyBaseViewModel()
   {
    //..implementation here
   }
}

public interface IRepository
{
  BaseViewModel GetMyBaseViewModel();
}
```

....
and in your controllers :
...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //private repository member
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        //controller constructors
        //injecting the repository here
        public HomeController() : this(new Repository()) 
        {

        }
        public HomeController(IRepository repository)
        {
          _repository = repository;
        }

        //methods that call the repository for the vm data context
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = _repository.GetMyBaseViewModel();
            return View();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make an abstract `ActionResult` method in your base controller:

```
protected BaseViewModel vm;

public ActionResult Index(string page, string title) {
    vm = new BaseViewModel(); 
    vm.Role = GetRoleNumber(User);
    vm.MenuItems = contentService.GetMenuItems("00", vm.Role);
    vm.Menu = pageService.GetMenu(vm.MenuItems, Request.FilePath);

    try
    {
        return IndexSupplemental();
    }
    catch(NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        // Log and move on; the abstract method is not implemented.
    }

    return View();
}

protected abstract ActionResult IndexSupplemental();
```

Then every controller would have to implement this abstract method.

Comment: But the new IndexSupplemental would need to know about the vm object that I constructed as the code after these four lines makes use of the vm object. Is there a way I could do that. I guess also I would need to pass the page and title up to IndexSupplemental.

Comment: @Angela you can pass it as a parameter to IndexSupplemental method.

Comment: While this a good solution for code reusability it automatically creates Index actions for derived controllers and forces you to implement a method you may not need. Although this can be perfectly fine depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can move it to a method in your base controller and call it when you need it.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected BaseViewModel _viewModel;

    public void InitializeViewModel() {

        vm = new BaseViewModel(); 
        vm.Role = GetRoleNumber(User);
        vm.MenuItems = contentService.GetMenuItems("00", vm.Role);
        vm.Menu = pageService.GetMenu(vm.MenuItems, Request.FilePath);
    }
}
```

An example:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index(string page, string title)
    {
        InitializeViewModel();

        DoSomething(_viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait this is good but I only need to do all of this for the Index action method. If I put this in the constructor it will get run all the time and I just need it for Index.

Comment: Thanks. The second method looks a lot better for me. What I am a bit confused on is how could I pass the parameters back. I will need vm, page and title in my Index action method in the controllers. Can you confirm I should rename my viewModel to _vm or something like that. Is the naming convention _xx for private and protected?

Comment: @Angela you can access the protected Viewmodel field from your child class by using _viewModel

Comment: It's entirely up to you. It's pretty common prefixing private instance fields with underscore. I guess protected fields are pascal cased but it doesn't matter which on you choose as long as you have a persistent style.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects most of my actions will return a viewmodel that inherits from the BaseViewModel but there are exceptions to this. So what I did was something like this in ControllerBase:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var authData = GetUserData();
        if (authData != null)
        {
            var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            if (result != null)
            {
                var vm = result.Model as ViewModelBase;
                if (vm != null)
                {
                    vm.UserId = authData.UserID;
                    vm.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

What you could do otherwise, as I expect your ViewModel to be of different types, is to create a method similar to this in ControllerBase:

**NOTE** This does not do what you want. I'm just showing a technique for creating a new instance of a derived class with some initialization code.

```
    protected T Command<T>() where T : BaseCommand, new()
    {
        var command = new T();
        command.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var authData = GetUserData();
            if (authData != null)
            {
                command.UserId = authData.UserID;

            }
        }
        return command;
    }
```

Which would be used as

```
var command = Command<CreateUserCommand>();
```